# What do we call a verb which is used to make a noun more specific?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Can anyone please advise what is the name of a verb which is used as a prefix to a noun to make that noun more specific..
Examples..
Roasting pan,

Baking tray,

Frying pan,

Assault rifle,

Walking stick,

Reading glasses

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `-ing` form is not always a verb. Second, it doesn't act as a `prefix` in your examples.

Most of your examples use [participles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) (an -ing form used as an adjective).

> Participles have various uses in a sentence. One use of a participle is simply as an adjective:
>
> A broken window. A fallen tree. An interesting book.
>
> [Wikipedia]

---

However, seeing that you also mentioned `assault rifle`, in case you're looking for a word that describes modifiers like these, I suggest

**[qualifier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/qualifier)**

> A word or phrase, especially an adjective, used to attribute a quality to another word, especially a noun. [Oxford]

An example to illustrate:

PHOEBE: No you can't quit college! No! You're in college? Really?

FRANK: Yeah, refrigerator college.

(Frank used a qualifier to make his point clearer)

Comment: Tushar! It’s been too long! Glad to see you’re still around and lending your expertise to the site. On the “qualifier” section, wouldn’t the “assault” in “assault rifle” be a particular kind of qualifier, specifically a *attributive noun*? I guess you could make the same case for “frying” in “frying pan” if you take up the other answer’s argument that such words are gerunds which are “*nouns* with the force of a verb”.

Comment: @DanBron: Too long indeed. I really hope my comeback sticks this time :)
 (Been a bit busy with my day job and pursuing a Master's at the same time.) I hope you're doing stellar.

Answer (score 1):

It's a gerund.  It really doesn't modify the noun.  For example, the walking stick is not actually walking.  It's a stick used for the purpose of walking.